# Deleted files from my home folder. How to recover them?

Tags: undelete

I've deleted accidentally files from my home folder and need to recover them. How can I do that?

I need a recovering software that points specifically to the folder where the files were deleted and searches for the files there (not at the entire partition) since I have an extremely active partition.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you only moved files into the trash, rather than actually deleting them, you will be able to restore your files by opening your file manager and browsing to the 'Trash folder'. When you open Trash you should be able to see your files. Right click on them and 'Restore' them they will appear back where they were prior to deleting them.

Answer (score 0):

If you used the default filesystem when installing (EXT4) you might have a chance with [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/). As always, there are no guarantees with trying to recover deleted files.